# offset one of matplotlib's legend items

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

In python's matplotlib, for an article on Newton's method I would like to visualize the first three iterations and the last one in an line graph, where each iterations shows up as a separate curve. The legend labels will be something like 'iteration 1', 'iteration 2', 'iteration 3', 'iteration 14'. For clarity I would like to visually offset the first three from the last, either with some white space or ideally with a triple dot to indicate the jump. Does anybody know of a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display 2 legends. The first with the 3 iterations and the second with the last iteration :

```
l1 = plt.legend(data_for, 3_iterations, loc=[1.01,0.6])
l2 = plt.legend(data_for, last_iteration, loc=[1.01,0.2])
plt.gca().add_artist(l1) # to add back first legend
```

`loc` allows you to choose the position of the legend. Here it will be on the right hand side of the figure, and l1 above l2. You can modify this to make it as clear as you wish.

For the triple dots you can add them with `plt.text(x,y,"...")` where x and y are coordinate where you want '...'.

If you edit your question with your code, with a working example, I may be more precise.

---

Other solution :

Lets say `leg` is the legend object, you can move some part of the legend. For instance if you want to move the second line (`[1]`) of the legend :

```
L2 = leg.get_lines()[1]
L2.set_ydata(np.array(L2.get_ydata())-2) # move down of 2 units the line (in the legend based coordinates)
```

To move the associated text :

```
T2 = leg.texts[1]
T2.set_y(-2)
```

and for the frame :

```
frame = leg.get_frame()
frame.set_height(frame.get_height()+20)
```

For the frame, it actually doesn't work for me I don't know why. Maybe it will work for you.
Alternatively, you can use :

```
leg=plt.legend(borderpad=2)
```

Step by step, you can set your legend. Can be long though, I would choose the first option, since you can remove the frame, it won't be noticeable.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I was thinking of shifting entries while still in a single box, but this is certainly a good backup solution. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like the type of solution I'm looking for, however when I try it out only the line shifts down, not the text. Also the bounding box is not enlarged to contain shifted contents. I had a brief look inside the legend object but cannot guess how to fix this.

Comment: Yes, you need to access the other object of the legend (text, and so on). I'll edit